# No wrapping wanted in a legend of a ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

If I run the following R code :

```
    g <- ggplot(results_table, aes(x = factor(results_table$Criteria, as.character(results_table$Criteria)), 
                               y = Pct*100)) + 
  geom_bar(aes (fill = factor(results_table$Criteria, as.character(results_table$Criteria))),
           stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=Palcolor) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), axis.line.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.line.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -0.3, unit = "cm"),size = 9)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)) +
  xlab("% of \nOrganizations") + 
  ylab("") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(sprintf("%0.1f", round(Pct*100, digits = 1)),"%"), vjust = -0.8, 
                hjust = 0.5), size = 3.2, color = "black")
```

it produces the following graph :
[image]

first question : I would like to have the legend's labels in one line, then no wrapping.
Second question : I would like to have smaller squares.
How can I proceed ?

Comment: Could you please include your data: `results_table` as an object eg  `results_table <- data.frame(...)` where ... represents the variables and values to make your question reproducible [reprex].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to include removal of line breaks from legend text to prevent wrapping, and functions to allow maximum space for legend presentation.

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

#### data

```
tib <- tibble(v1 = letters[1:7],
              v2 = 7:1,
              g = c("long legend text, blah di blah blah blah, blah di blah  blah blah 1",
                    "long legend text, blah di blah blah blah, blah di blah  blah blah 2",
                    "long legend text, blah di blah blah blah\nwith a line break 3",
                    "long legend text, blah di blah blah blah, blah di blah  blah blah 4",
                    "long legend text, blah di blah blah blah, blah di blah  blah blah 5",
                    "long legend text, blah di blah blah blah\nwith a line break 6",
                    "long legend text, blah di blah blah blah, blah di blah  blah blah 7"))
```

#### data wrangle

```
# remove line break with base r
tib$g <- gsub("\\n", "", tib$g)

# or with dplyr and stringr
tib <- mutate(tib, g = str_remove(g, "\\n"))
```

#### plot

```
ggplot(tib, aes(v1, v2, fill = g)) +
  geom_col()+
  labs(fill = NULL)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.size = unit(3, "mm"), #smaller squares
        legend.box.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = "mm"), #maximise legend extents
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8))+ #modify text size to fit  
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, that's what I find it weird too, as there isn't effectively no line break in the field 'Criteria'.

Comment: OK. will add soon.

Comment: Indeed there are well breaks in the values of criteria, but it is detected only when the values are printed in the console :

Comment: Indeed there are well breaks in the values of criteria, but it is detected only when the values are printed in the console.: :>results_table$Criteria
[1] At Market (50th Percentile)                      No Policy                                       
[3] Above Market (60th to 74th Percentile)           Slightly Above Market (51st to 59th\nPercentile)
[5] Slightly Below Market (45th to 49th\nPercentile) Below Market (44th Percentile or Lower)         
[7] Well Above Market (75th Percentile or\nHigher)

Comment: Brillant ! Actually that's exactly what I have done in parallel. But if hadn't fix it, you provide me the right solution. Thanks you so much !

Comment: similar solution in my case : results_table$Criteria <- gsub("\\\n"," ", results_table$Criteria)